# Find Element in Max Heap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, max-heap

I have a MaxPQ Heap that uses an array to store the elements. What is an algorithm I could use to find a given element in the heap ? The algorithm I am currently using iterates through the array starting with the index 1 and upto the number of elements added to the heap. This algorithm has a complexity of O(N), is there an algorithm with complexity O(logN) ?

Comment: If you [heapify](http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C455/html/notes/Chapter6/heapify.htm) your heap after every insertion, you should have the max/min element in your root depending if your heap is a max/min heap

Comment: I'm not looking to to get the max element. I am looking to find a random key that is given by the user.

Answer (score 8):

If you have *only* an array representing a heap (min or max) than I'm afraid a worst-case logarithmic algorithm is not to be found, since starting at the top of the tree you aren't going to be able to tell in general which subtree to search.  If your root is 100 and its children are 90 and 80, and you are looking for a 5, you've got to (in general) explore both paths.

Now if you keep an auxiliary data structure around which tracks the position in the array of your keys, you *can* hack in a constant time lookup.  I found the following description at http://eclipse.wells.edu/badams/courses/cs322/notes/topics/tools/heap.html

> To find an arbitrary element, it helps to maintain an additional array indexed by node names and keyed by their position in the heap (either a pointer, or an index number). That makes lookup of an arbitrary node work in constant time, and maintaining the data in the array only requires a fixed number of steps for each bubbling operation, so doesn't change the asymptotic time for heapify up or down.

Again, given just the heap, your worst-case will be linear, though you might get a little bit of a speedup in practice if you traverse the heap and do some pruning.

Comment: I kind of assumed there wouldn't be a best case of O(log N) since the only relation between the children is that they are less than their parent. Would there be an algo with avg complexity O(log N) ?

Comment: If one exists, it's really hard to find via googling. :)  Average case complexity is pretty hard to measure.  What are the usual ranges of keys?  Bounded integers? Strings?  Will most of your queries be of the found or not found type?  I suspect such an algorithm does not exist but I cannot prove it.  The only thing we can say about a max heap is that the value of a node is larger than all the values in its subtree.  How does that help with search?  It lets you do some pruning.  _On average_ does that imply amortized logarithmic time?  My hunch is no, but we need an expert to weigh in here.

Comment: @Ray Toal how about storing the largest key at each level in an auxiliary data structure. Initial search to find out the level will need at most O(log n) time. And once we have the level, there are only a limited number of elements to search from. Do you think it would fetch me something?

Comment: I don't see how that would help.  Knowing the largest key at each level doesn't tell you which subtree to search.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to keep a hash if the there are values from 0 to N and only m nodes and you dont want to keep an array of N size?